# How to post password from iOS app to PHP server securely?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, substring

I know almost nothing about internet security, and I came across this question.

The situation is:

The user has to login to PHP based server from iOS app.

I did POST sending to php from xcode something like this:

```
NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@&password=%@",usernameVar, passwordVar];

NSData *parameterData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mywebsite.com/server.php"];

request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPBody:parameterData];
```

But is this secure? I have feeling that sending password in plain text is quiet dangerous.

If so, can anybody tell me how to securely post password?

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231905/ios-security-sending-data-with-password-to-and-from-server)

Comment: @JoonP please replace NSASCIIStringEncoding with NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: You can encrypt your password with a shared hash with you PHP backend. Then, you can send the password on HTTP Headers

Comment: Just post data over HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply encrypt your password and decrypt at server end.

You can also see this link this library do the same what you are looking for https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor.

**Or**

Here is a sample code for AES256 Encryption and Decryption.

Download the AES256 encryption classes from here:https://gist.github.com/838614.

**Objective C Code :**

```
    NSString *key = @"a16byteslongkey!";
    NSString *plaintext = @"iphone";

    NSString *ciphertext = [plaintext AES256EncryptWithKey: key];
    NSLog(@"ciphertext: %@", ciphertext);
```

Send your encrypted password in the link of api. And at server end decrypt the password. or simply store the encrypted password you can also match the encrypted password.

**PHP Code :**

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = "a16byteslongkey!";
    $plaintext = "iphone";
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);
    echo "ciphertext: ".$ciphertext."<br/>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass the confidential data in HTTP Header it will be secure.

And you can also convert password to MD5 format so it will not be readable in simple alphanumeric string.